# unable to evaluate expression whilst debugging

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2013

When debugging asp.net code (running against IIS, and using Visual studio 2013) and in a breakpoint and trying to evaluate a variable using quick watch i quite often get "unable to evaluate expression".

deleting the .suo from the asp.net project folder seems to resolve the issue (After reloading the solution)

Is this a recognised bug? getting this a lot now in Visual studio 2013 on more than one machine.

Comment: I've seen this too.  In my case, I suspect it has something to do with debugging a process that has multiple AppDomains loaded.  Do you have more than one application in your app pool?

Comment: Have to compiled in debug-mode? Is it a single project or are multile projects included?

Comment: @jlew only have one application in the app pool. tim-schmelter yes its compiled as debug mode...

Comment: Out of desperation I rebooted my system and it magically started working again...

Comment: deleting the suo. file helped me a lot

Answer (score 97):

I faced it today with VS2013.

> Goto Tools --> Options --> Debugging --> General -->
> Scroll to the bottom for "Use Managed Compatibility Mode" and Select the option.

Screenshot from the blog(url below):
[image]
Restart you debugging.

*What Helped Me is below!*

> - [Visual Studio 2013 Could not evaluate Expression Debugger Abnormality](http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2013/Nov/21/Visual-Studio-2013-Could-not-evaluate-Expression-Debugger-Abnormality)
>   turned out to be very helpful.
> - Also, you could see @Dreamers answer [Unable to debug managed code using visual studio 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21152820/769678)

Comment: Thanks a lot .Great answer. :)

Comment: I did this and it makes no difference, I've been debugging C# and C++ for years and for the last few days I cannot view my c++ member variables no matter what options I choose using VS2015.

Comment: Followed your steps but still not getting result!!

Comment: **!** Note that some features don't work along with Managed Compatibility Mode (such as real-time code modifications, performance measurement tools etc.)

Comment: For me this option is grayed out

Answer (score 8):

The C# debugging engine relies heavily on the CLR debugger in order to evaluate expressions.  That message indicates that the CLR is in a state in which it is unable to perform simple evaluations and the reasons for that can include the following

- a local variable is optimized away
- the thread is stopped in a GC unsafe point
- a previous function call caused the debugger to get into a bad state and hence further evaluations simply aren't possible

Comment: this message is something i've only noticed in vs2013 RTM don't remember noticing it (when debugging) in vs2013RC (and beta), 2012 or 2010.

Answer (score 7):

Some of these options change over time - and top rated solutions in other answers don't seem to all exist any more - searching the options dialog can help.

Right now for a ASPNET Core project I found [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/general-debugging-options-dialog-box), and enabling it seems to be helping:

[image]

> Suppress JIT optimization on module load (Managed only): Disables the
>   JIT optimization of managed code when a module is loaded and JIT is
>   compiled while the debugger is attached. Disabling optimization may
>   make it easier to debug some problems, although at the expense of
>   performance. If you are using Just My Code, suppressing JIT
>   optimization can cause non-user code to appear as user code ("My
>   Code"). For more information, see JIT optimization and debugging.

If it doesn't seem to help I'd suggest turning it off again.

Comment: oh thanks , still works for vs 2019 to evulate linq queries

Comment: This helped me with my 2019 Visual Studio trying to look a closer look at datasets during debugging at runtime. Before setting that, everything was "unable to evaluate expression".

Comment: This broke ReSharper's test runner for me. Asked me locate the Program.cs file in some strange temp directory. I had to turn it off again to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this for specific project and the reason is Costura.Fody (embeds all DLLs into the executing assembly).

In this case you can disable  [Costura.Fody.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35266578/how-to-disable-costura-fody-resources-embedding-in-debug-mode)

1. Comment out Costura from FodyWever.xml

   ```
   <Weavers>
     <!--<Costura />-->
   </Weavers>
   ```
2. Disable the clean reference target (if included) in *.csproj

   ```
   <!--<Target Name="CleanReferenceCopyLocalPaths" AfterTargets="AfterBuild">
       <Delete Files="@(ReferenceCopyLocalPaths->'$(OutDir)%
        (DestinationSubDirectory)%(Filename)%(Extension)')" />
       <Exec Command="DeleteEmptyDirectory.bat" />
     </Target>-->
   ```

Comment: In my case this was the solution so worth the effort.

Answer (score -4):

Go to `Tools --> Options --> Environment --> General -->` check "Automatically adjust visual experience based on client performance" option.