# Visual Studio 2015 using Linq in conditional breakpoint

Tags: c#, linq, debugging

Is it possible to use Linq within a conditional breakpoint?

I'm attempting to break when the following condition is true:

```
parentElement.ChildElements.Any(c => c.Id == 1)
```

When ever the debugger is hit the following error message is displayed

> The debugger is unable to evaluate this expression.

I have tried the following condition in case the issue was related to using `.Any()`

```
parentElement.ChildElements.Where(c => c.Id == 1).Count() > 0
```

This resulted in the same error as above being displayed.

I know a work around would be the following code

```
#if DEBUG
if(parentElement.ChildElements.Any(c => c.Id == 1))
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
}
#endif
```

However, I would ideally not like to make code changes to place a debugger.

Comment: Dont like conditional breakpoint, it slow down the execution several times

Comment: just verified - linq works fine for conditional breakpoints

Comment: I think my issue may be related to not enabling 'Use Managed Compatibility Mode' in debugging options. Enabling this setting allows the breakpoint act as expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was caused by the `Use Managed Compatibility Mode` option not being enabled within Visual Studio.

Once this option was checked the breakpoint performed as expected.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30532248) answer for how to enable this option within Visual Studio.