# Simple conditional breakpoint throws error in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, breakpoints

I have following code:

```
IEnumerable<Example> examples = someCollection.Where(x => x.IsExample);
object result = examples.SingleOrDefault() ?? (object)DBNull.Value;
return result;
```

My intention is to use a conditional breakpoint for line 2 to stop execution, if the condition `examples.Count() != 1` is met.

Visual Studo returns an error message saying *The condition for a breakpoint failed to execute.[...] The error returned was 'The expression cannot be evaluated. [...]'*

However, when I added the line `var count = examples.Count()` and changed the condition of my breakpoint to `count != 1` it worked fine.

Is this some kind of bug or is there a reasonable explanation for this error?

Comment: As a side issue - I **strongly** suggest returning `null` rather than `DBNull`. `DBNull` is terrible for type safety.

Comment: `examples.Count()` is a Linq statement which is being applied to an `IEnumerable<T>`, that would cause the previous line to be executed multiple times, I wouldn't recommend that.

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42855604/visual-studio-2015-using-linq-in-conditional-breakpoint help?

Comment: The reasonable explanation is that executing LINQ is expensive (e.g. may involve a database request), and the debugger is likely reluctant to do so. Using `var count = ` sidesteps the issue - now the expense is still there but it is expensive in terms of **your program**  (which is fine, the debugger doesn't need to be worried about your code being slow - since you wrote it as part of the program) rather than the debugger (in which case the VS team will be blamed for the slowness).

Comment: Also, have you considered instead putting a breakpoint on the *last* line of code that checks whether `result` is equal to `DBNull.Value`? That will be *way* faster (and work!), since it means the LINQ will be executed just once (as part of prorgram execution) and the conditional breakpoint won't need any LINQ check at all.

Comment: @mjwills Thank you for your comments. This seems legit.

Comment: Awesome. Again, I'd strongly recommend moving away from `DBNull`. You will save yourself much heartache.

Comment: @mjwills a better explanation as to *why not use DBNull* in this case would be `null` means the absence of a reference to an object and `DBNull` represents an uninitialized variant or nonexistent database column. @@Erik T. [See](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dbnull?view=netframework-4.8) this to learn more.

Comment: I'd suggest type safety is a better argument @Çöđěxěŕ - but sure, that is a good reason too.

Comment: Strange debugger quirk, it is for some reason fretting over the thread's ManagedThreadId property.  Let's call it a bug, the current debugging engine has rather a lot of them.  The old one works well, use Tools > Option > Debugging > General, tick "Use Managed Debugging Mode".  That selects the debugging engine last used in VS2010, it is much more stable.