# Why my VS2015 could not get the value in watch window during debug?

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2015

I could not get the variable's value when the project in debug mode.
in the watch window, it shows some error, or if move the mouse on the variable, just nothing happened. does someone has any idea about it?[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5DUVK.jpg)

Comment: Maybe you can get some help from this [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21166874/unable-to-evaluate-expression-whilst-debugging).

Comment: Hi friend, any update for this issue?

Comment: @LanceLi-MSFT, not yet. but i just install the Express 2015 for windows desktop. and it works now..

Comment: Hi Storm, have you tried to repair your VS2015, and make sure you've updated it to VS2015 Update3. I think this issue has something related to something broken in VS.

Comment: @LanceLi-MSFT, I tried to repair it, but still not work, anyway now I could work with Express version, so i stop to debug this problem with the professional version. and Thanks for your hints.