# "Condition for a breakpoint failed to execute… 'variable' not declared. It may be inaccessible…" Why?

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2013, breakpoints, visual-studio-debugging, conditional-breakpoint

> <sub>**Related questions:**</sub>
>
> - <sub>[Unable to debug managed code using visual studio 2013 ("Cannot evaluate expression" error - am using debug build) (Note that VS 2012 works)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21152630/unable-to-debug-managed-code-using-visual-studio-2013-cannot-evaluate-expressi)</sub>
> - <sub>[VS2013 Debugger + Entity Framework: "runtime has refused to evaluate the expression", crashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19843683/vs2013-debugger-entity-framework-runtime-has-refused-to-evaluate-the-express)</sub>

I am facing a problem with conditional breakpoints in Visual Studio 2013 Professional. The breakpoint condition is referring to a local variable (`tagString`), which is declared and initialized in the line of code immediately preceding the breakpoint. Upon encountering the breakpoint, the debugger claims that…

> *The condition for a breakpoint failed to execute. The condition was `tagString.Contains("…")`. The error returned was '`tagString` is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.'*

This error message does not appear to make any sense, because the variable *is* declared and accessible:

[image: Screenshot demonstrating the issue]

I am running a Debug build of this code. Why does the debugger claim that the local variable is not defined, and how can I resolve this issue?

---

**P.S.:** I've just realised that the conditional breakpoint not working is only a small part of a larger problem: The debugger also cannot *Watch* that variable, nor will it be displayed in the *Locals* window.

**P.P.S:** I've tried the recommendations given in [Rick Strahl's blog post, "Visual Studio 2013 'Could not evaluate Expression' Debugger Abnormality"](http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2013/Nov/21/Visual-Studio-2013-Could-not-evaluate-Expression-Debugger-Abnormality), to no avail.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to debug managed code using visual studio 2013 ("Cannot evaluate expression" error - am using debug build) (Note that VS 2012 works)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21152630/unable-to-debug-managed-code-using-visual-studio-2013-cannot-evaluate-expressi)